# Search drive for excel dependencies

Tags: excel, vba, dependencies

I am currently simplifying a file structure of a company. It is a total mess. 
Currently I am doing the finance department, which has allot of dependencies between excel files. These files I cannot migrate to the new structure, because the location changes and the dependencies is lost.

Therefore I am in search of a tool to scan a folder and its sub-folders for excel dependencies. I want to list these and say: hey guys, what about these files?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below

- opens each file that sits in or below the directory specified by `strStartFolder` (ie "C:\temp") in this example using a recursive `Dir`
- looks for any file links in each file
- uses an array to hold then populate the final results

Pls change your path in `strStartFolder` to suit

*This code was formerly published as an article on another forum*

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Public StrArray()
Public lngCnt As Long

Public Sub Main()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strStartFolder As String

'Setup Application for the user
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With

'reset public variables
lngCnt = 0
ReDim StrArray(1 To 4, 1 To 1000)

strStartFolder = "c:\temp"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Format output sheet
Set WB = Workbooks.Add(1)
Set ws = WB.Worksheets(1)
ws.[a1] = Now()
ws.[a2] = strStartFolder
ws.[a1:a3].HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft

ws.[A4:D4].Value = Array("Folder", "File", "Linked File", "Linked File Path")
ws.Range([a1], [c4]).Font.Bold = True
ws.Rows(5).Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True


Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strStartFolder)

' Start the code to gather the files
ShowSubFolders objFolder, True
ShowSubFolders objFolder, False

If lngCnt > 0 Then
    ' Finalise output
    With ws.Range(ws.[a5], ws.Cells(5 + lngCnt - 1, 4))
        .Value2 = Application.Transpose(StrArray)
        .Offset(-1, 0).Resize(Rows.Count - 3, 4).AutoFilter
        .Offset(-4, 0).Resize(Rows.Count, 4).Columns.AutoFit
    End With
    ws.[a1].Activate
Else
    MsgBox "No files found!", vbCritical
    WB.Close False
End If

' tidy up

Set objFSO = Nothing

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .StatusBar = vbNullString
End With
End Sub


Sub ShowSubFolders(ByVal objFolder, bRootFolder As Boolean)

Dim colFolders As Object
Dim objSubfolder As Object
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim lnkSources
Dim lnk

'strName must be a variant, as ParseName does not work with a string argument
Dim strFname
Set colFolders = objFolder.SubFolders
Application.StatusBar = "Processing " & objFolder.Path

If bRootFolder Then
    Set objSubfolder = objFolder
    GoTo OneTimeRoot
End If

For Each objSubfolder In colFolders
    'check to see if root directory files are to be processed
OneTimeRoot:
    strFname = Dir(objSubfolder.Path & "\*.xls*")
    Do While Len(strFname) > 0
        Set WB = Workbooks.Open(objSubfolder.Path & "\" & strFname, False)
        lnkSources = WB.LinkSources
        If Not IsEmpty(lnkSources) Then
            For Each lnk In lnkSources
                lngCnt = lngCnt + 1
                If lngCnt Mod 1000 = 0 Then ReDim Preserve StrArray(1 To 4, 1 To (lngCnt + 1000))
                StrArray(1, lngCnt) = WB.Path
                StrArray(2, lngCnt) = WB.Name
                StrArray(3, lngCnt) = Left$(lnk, InStrRev(lnk, "\"))
                StrArray(4, lngCnt) = Right$(lnk, Len(lnk) - InStrRev(lnk, "\"))
            Next

        End If
        WB.Close False
        strFname = Dir
    Loop
    If bRootFolder Then
        bRootFolder = False
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ShowSubFolders objSubfolder, False
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: allright, this looks nice!
I dont wont to bother to much, but can I use these workbooks in C# also? I have way more experience with that..