# Documenting Excel

Tags: excel, documentation, er-diagram

We have hundreds if not thousands of Excel files in the organization, with some having dependencies and links to others. So far these Excel files have been used as islands of information, and it is my effort to put some sanity to this.

I was thinking of having something similar to an ER diagram wherein we could list out all Excel files and then link the ones which have dependencies to others, all with visual drag/drop.

Is there something available (preferably free) that does this, or can someone suggest how to approach the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: while not a visual diagram, this question produces a list you may be able to use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186995/search-drive-for-excel-dependencies

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache POI http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html

That will give you an API to work with so you can write some sort of batch process.

Here is the basic way one cell in a workbook can be dependent on a cell from another workbook:

1. Open both the workbook that will contain the link (called the
   destination workbook), and the workbook that contains the data you
   want to link to (called the source workbook).
2. In the destination workbook, click Save Button image.
3. Select a cell or cells you want to link from. (If you are creating a new formula, type (an equal sign).
4. If you are entering the link elsewhere in the formula, type the operator or function that you want to precede the link.

So you can use this java library to parse through the excel file, and then you can use the cell formula to pull in the dependencies.

At that point I would create some sort of database and populate it as your program you wrote parses through files. Or maybe you could just create a file system that represents such a database.

Table: excel
Rows: id (bigint), filename (varchar)

Table: excel_deps
Rows: id (bigint), dep_id (bigint)

For each excel spreadsheet, create a row in "excel"

For each dependency, create a row in excel_deps for the ID of the spreadsheet and the ID of the spreadsheet it is dependent upon.

Oh and you asked about something with drag and drop. The database table that this populates could be used to generate a Graph of dependencies very simply using something like JFreeChart or the Java graphics api.